# Swagger - Array of key-value pairs with unknown keys

Tags: arrays, forms, api, swagger

I am trying to write a Swagger API document but I am having issues with one particular scenario.

I have a huge grid with id references in each (think Chess Board) and I want to send grid references that have changed and the new ID in each. So I may have a 40x40 grid and I change one of the grid squares to a different value.

I want to send to my API :

```
12x21 = 12345
23x11 = 87654
42x01 = 12987
23x09 = 19283
```

Without having to list every single grid position in swagger as a parameter, how can I represent this scenario using Swagger UI?

Answer (score 0):

I would design one endpoint where you send the change to as a PUT request (or a POST request if it is a new id, it's hard to tell from the context), with the actual change as the JSON body of your request. The reference to your grid could then either be sent as query parameters or as part of the JSON body.